# definite article 'the' before a comparative degree of adjective

Tags: articles, adjectives, usage, comparative, functions

> This was **the more** remarkable because I was found unable to answer a single question in the Latin paper.

Reference: FIRST YEAR AT HARROW by Winston S. Churchill

In this sentence, the definite article 'the' is used before a comparative degree of the adjective 'more'. Generally definite article 'the' is used before superlative degrees of adjectives. So what is the application of the definite article 'the' here in this sentence?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How does "the + comparative adjective" work here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/342001/how-does-the-comparative-adjective-work-here/342598)

Comment: It is not a comparative as there is no comparison. But it’s an intensifier of some sort.